# Add product to amazon using M2epro and Ignore custom option

Tags: magento-1.9, m2epro

I want to list simple products without custom options to Amazon using **M2epro** module. 
I have all simple type products with custom options but I don't want to use custom options on Amazon. Can anyone have any idea that how we can ignore the custom options in m2epro and how we can customize the code?

Please help

Thanks